# ioncube loader, doesn't work Error

Tags: php, encode, php-7.1, ioncube

When I start the file what need the encoder, I get this fatal error:

```
Fatal error: The file C:\xampp\htdocs\WeFact\Pro\index.php was encoded by the ionCube Encoder for PHP 5.6 and cannot run under PHP 7.1. Please ask the provider of the script to provide a version encoded with the ionCube Encoder for PHP 7.1. in Unknown on line 0
```

But in the readme file mentioned that this is the `PHP 7.1` encoder.

does someone know how I can solve this?

Comment: who's readme, ioncubes or the apps?

Comment: @delboy1978uk it was in the download, but i have already fixed it. thx for your patience!

Comment: Don't forget you can always create a support ticket at https://support.ioncube.com too. :)